# Displaying Images on Visualforce pages using Base64 Blob

Tags: apex, visualforce, images, base64

My question is about displaying base64 blob as image in visualforce page. Here's my controller code:

```
Object img;
public Object getImg () {
    List<ContentVersion> bodyList = [SELECT VersionData FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId='the real id'];

    img = bodyList[0].get('VersionData');
    return img;
}
```

Here's the visualforce:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{! img }"/>
```

This is getting rendered as

> `<img src="data:image/png;base64,core.filemanager.FileBlobValue@1e76577f">`

How can I get the actual base64 of image so the image is displayed properly?

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out after debugging a bit more.

```
Blob img;
public Object getImg () {
    List<ContentVersion> bodyList = [SELECT VersionData FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId='insert your id'];

    img = (Blob) bodyList[0].get('VersionData');
    return EncodingUtil.base64Encode(img);
}
```

All I had to do was to typecast the Object as Blob and then encode the blob value.